# How to use psql command line to remotely save multiple FOR loop results to remote client files?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have an anonymous function containing a query within a FOR loop that executes 100 times, and I need to save the 100 result sets as 100 files on the remote client (*not* on the server).

It seems like the psql `\copy` meta-command should be the way to do this, but I'm at a loss. Something of this form, maybe?

```
\copy (anonymous_function_w/_FOR_loop_here) to 'filename.txt'
```

where *filename.txt* is built from the FOR loop variable's value in each iteration. That's important - the files on the remote client need to be named based on the FOR loop's variable.

Is there any way to pull this off? I suppose an alternative approach would be to UNION all 100 query results into one big result, with the FOR loop's variable value in one field, and then use bash scripting to split it into 100 appropriately named files. But my bash skills are pretty lame. If psql can do the job directly that would be great.

EDIT: I should add that here's what the FOR loop variable looks like:

```
FOR rec IN SELECT DISTINCT county FROM voter.counties
```

so the file name would be built from rec.county + '.txt'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach to this is to use a SQL statement that generates the necessary statements, spool the output into a script file, then run that file.

Something like:

```
-- prepare for a "plain" output without headers or something similar
\a
\t 

-- spool the output into export.sql
\o export.sql
select format('\copy (select * from some_table where county = %L) to ''%s.txt''', county, county)
from (select distinct county from voter.counties) t;

-- turn spooling off
\o 

-- run the generated file
\i export.sql
```

So for each county name in `voters.counties` the `export.sql` will contain:

```
\copy (select * from some_table where county = 'foobar') to 'foobar.txt'
```

Comment: I want to express my gratitude for your very helpful answer. Because I'm not a pro, I find it easiest to learn by starting with an example relevant to my needs, then going back over the documentation to make sure I understand exactly what it's doing. In this particular case, I learned a ton about psql - which had previously just bewildered me - and about the postgreSQL `format` function - which I was unaware of - by working my way through your answer. Now I just need to figure out how to escape all the many apostrophes in the `concat` function inside my SQL query...but I'll get there.

Comment: @CheesyGrits: don't use `concat()` use `format()` that makes the whole "escaping" a lot easier

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong: the single-quote immediately preceding `%s.txt` in your example shouldn't be there, right? I.e., that line should read `select format('\copy (select * from some_table where county = %L) to %s.txt', county, county)
from (select distinct county from voter.counties) t;` Yes?

Comment: @CheesyGrits: it actually should be two single quotes to get them _into_ the string.